# How does $\frac{x + \frac{1}{2}}{\frac{1}{x} + 2} = \frac{x}2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How does simplifying $\dfrac{x+\frac12}{\frac1x+2}=\dfrac{x}2$

Plugging and chugging seems to prove this, but I don’t understand the algebra behind it.

How would you simplify $\dfrac{x+\frac12}{\frac1x+2}$ to get $\dfrac{x}2$?

I tried multiplying the expression by $x/x$, but that left me with $\frac{x^2+\frac{x}2}{1+2x}$

Is the fact that $\frac1x$ and $2$ are the reciprocals of $x$ and $\frac12$ respectively of any significance?

Thanks!

Comment: Simply multiply both denominator and numerator in $x$. What would it yield to?

Comment: Is it $$\frac{x+\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{1}{x}+2}=\frac{x}{2}$$?

Comment: @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner - Yes, that is it.

Comment: @Mostafa Ayaz - Doesn’t multiplying both the numerator and denominator by x yield (x^2 + (x/2)) / (1 + 2x)? Can that be simplified any further?

Comment: Absolutely! We have $x^2+x/2=x(x+0.5)$ and $1+2x=2(x+0.5)$

Comment: the algebra may be more clear if you multiply by $\frac{2x}{2x}$, rather than $\frac{x}{x}$

Comment: @GrantKing Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 8):

> Is the fact that $\frac1x$ and $2$ are the reciprocals of $x$ and $\frac12$ respectively of any significance?

Yes, and in general (assuming that $\,a \ne 0, b \ne 0 ,a + b \ne 0\,$):

$$\require{cancel}
\frac{a+b}{\;\;\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b}\;\;} = \dfrac{a+b}{\;\;\dfrac{a+b}{ab}\;\;} = \dfrac{\cancel{(a+b)}ab}{\cancel{a+b}} = ab
$$

The posted question is the particular case $\,a=x, b=\dfrac{1}{2}\,$.

Comment: That’s interesting. I’ve never seen that before. This explains it. Thank you!

Comment: @GrantKing For yet another interpretation, in the case $\,a,b \gt 0\,$ the above is equivalent to the relation between the arithmetic, harmonic and geometric means of *two* numbers [$\,A \cdot H = G^2\,$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mean#Two_numbers).

Answer (score 6):

I'd start by multiplying by $2/2$, to make the expression easier to read.

$$\frac{x + 1/2}{1/x + 2} = \frac{2x + 1}{2/x + 4} = \frac{2x^2 + x}{4x + 2}$$

Factoring the top and bottom:

$$\frac{2x^2 + x}{4x + 2} = \frac{x(2x + 1)}{2(2x + 1)}$$

And cancel:

$$\frac{x(2x + 1)}{2(2x + 1)} = \frac{x}{2}$$

Comment: If $$x\ne -\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: @Reese - Thank you! I understand how that works.

Answer (score 4):

When $x\ne -\dfrac12$
$$\dfrac{x+\dfrac12}{\dfrac1x+2}=\dfrac{\dfrac{2x+1}{2}}{\dfrac{2x+1}{x}}=\dfrac x2$$

Answer (score 3):

Let $x \not = -1/2$.

Factor the numeratior :

$x+1/2 = (x/2)(2+1/x)$.

Then :

$\dfrac{x+1/2}{1/x+2} = $

$\dfrac{(x/2)(2+1/x)}{1/x+2}= x/2.$

Answer (score 2):

If $x \neq \frac{-1}{2}$, then $\frac{(x+1/2)}{(1/x+2)} = \frac{x^2+x/2}{1+2x} = \frac{2x^2+x}{2+4x}$. This is multiplying by 2 on top and on the bottom. Note that we can write $x = \frac{2x+4x^2}{2+4x}$. Therefore $\frac{x}{2} = \frac{x+2x^2}{2+4x}$, and the expressions are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

We have that for $x\neq -\frac12$ multiplying both side by $(1/x + 2)$

$$\frac{x + 1/2}{\frac1x + 2}=\frac x 2$$

$$\frac{x + 1/2}{\frac1x + 2}\left(\frac1x +2\right)=\frac x 2 \left(\frac1x +2\right)$$

$$x + \frac12=\frac12+x$$

For $x=-\frac12$ the equality doesn’t hold.